# Filepond + Pintura Vue 2 converts SVG to PNG

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, filepond

im using [Filepond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/) in combination with [Pintura](https://pqina.nl/pintura/) and Vue 2.

[Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzDAn.png)

I configured the Vue Filepond component with Pintura and the Filepond Image Editor Plugin. As so far everything runs good. However, when I upload an SVG image now, it is converted to a PNG image after the upload.

Is there a way to keep the SVG? I dont want to convert the image.

Comment: Pintura doesn't support editing SVGs at the time. You'll have to exclude SVGs from editing, you can do so with the `imageEditorSupportImage` hook. https://pqina.nl/pintura/docs/v8/getting-started/installation/filepond/

Comment: @Rik thanks! Now im checking for the uploaded meme type and toggle `imageEditorWriteImage` to skip the SVG conversion.